# Assign an image resource to ImageView according to a flag

Tags: android, onclick, imageview, flags

I have to change the image dsiplayed in the `ImageView`, when user click on it. And when he clicks it again, I want to show the original image. How to do this with the flags?

Supposably:

```
imageView1, R.drawable.pic_one, R.drawable.pic_two.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a boolean flag for two states, if you need more, use a byte or int and use the switch-case structure

```
private boolean tmp;

imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        tmp = !tmp;
        imageView.setImageResource(tmp ? R.drawable.image1 : R.drawable.image2);
   }
 });
```

Comment: Oh, thanx ! I'll use it

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use `selector` for selected state and then following code.

sample code:

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
      imageView.setSelected(!imageView.isSelected());
   }
});
```